# Question about Column Space and Row Space of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If $rank(A)=1$ and $Null(A) \perp Col(A)$, then we have that $dim(Col(A))=1$ right? Then that also means that $dim(Row(A))=1$. So is it true that $$Col(A)=Row(A)$$ since they are both perpendicular to $Null(A)$ and they both have dimension of $1$?

Comment: This question only makes sense if $A$ is square, but if so, yes this is true.

Comment: The logic seems tortured and it is not at all clear to me what you are asking. Also, are you assuming something about the size of matrix $A$. What if $A$ is $n$ x $1$ ?

Comment: Why should two subspaces with the same dimension be equal?

Comment: I apologize. A is a square $n\times n$ matrix. We know $Null(A) \perp Col(A)$, $Null(A) \perp Row(A)$ and $dim(Col(A))=dim(Row(A))=1$. So my question is that since they are both perpendicular to $Null(A)$ and have the same dimension, are they equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim(\text{Col}(A))+\dim(\text{null}(A))=n$, so if $\dim(\text{Col}(A))=1$, then $\dim(\text{null}(A))=n-1$.

If you know what the orthogonal complement of a vector subspace $W$ is, which is denoted by $W^\perp$, then you probably know $\dim(W^\perp)+\dim(W)=n$, which in this case implies $\dim((\text{null}(A))^\perp)=1$. Since any vector subspace orthogonal to $\text{null}(A)$ must be a subspace of $(\text{null}(A))^\perp$, then $\text{Col}(A),\text{Row}(A)\subseteq(\text{null}(A))^\perp$. Since the three of them have dimension $1$, they are all equal.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much!